# Sort an array from two sides at the same time

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

One of my exercise is an array of 10 char that I have to sort.
In fact, the array is in a random order, and every elements have a char that represents a ball (G = Green, R = Red, B = Blue).

I have to sort this array, so that all the R balls will come to the start of the array the G to the end and the Blue in the middle.
Moreover I have to do this with a low time complexity and memory complexity.
I tried this and I success only to put the Red balls in the begging of the array.

This is my code :

```
char arr[10] = {
    'R', 'G', 'B',
    'G', 'G', 'R',
    'B', 'R', 'G',
    'B'
};

for (int i = 0, j = 10; i < 10-1, j > i; i++, j--)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
    {
        if (arr[k] == 'R')
        {
            char temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[k];
            arr[k] = temp;
        }
        if (arr[k] == 'G')
        {
            char temp2 = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[k];
            arr[k] = arr[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code with the debugger?

Comment: This is work for the Red balls, but after that I don't know how to sort the Green balls in the same loop.

Comment: W h a t  d i d  y o u  o b s e r v e? What are the variable values at each step?

Comment: `i < 10-1, j > i` doesn't do what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the very limited domain of elements in your array, you can trivially solve this with (a simplified form of) [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

1. Create three counters, one each for red, green, and blue, initialized each for 0.
2. Count the occurrences of each of the three.
3. Overwrite the array - first with red to the number you found, then blue, then green.

Comment: Thanks but all the exercise I to really sort the array and not to overwrite it.

Comment: See my edit in the code, in order to help me to solve my problem

Comment: Hint: you said you know how to move all the reds to the front of the loop. Obviously, you can modify this to move, in a separate loop, all greens to the end of the loop. First apply your first loop, then the second one. The fact that it's two loops does *not* make this less efficient (it's the same complexity).

Answer (score 1):

You have only three colors, so you'll have repetitions in your array. In this case it's easier to start with these than with the original positions. Just count how many reds, blues, greens are there, then write that many of each to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Following edit should make it work

```
    for (int i = 0, j = 9; i < 10-1, j > 1; i++, j--)
```